# Can overheated graphics card damage other PC components on motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, temperature

I have a GTX 1080 SEAHAWK graphics card that usually has temperature around 96 Celsius. Since it (usually) does not crash my system, I have used it many hours to play demanding PC games. I am worried if I continue playing games with this overheated graphics card, it may damage my motherboard and other components on it. Can overheated graphics cards damage PC components nearby? If so, is 96 Celsius (over maximum safe temperature for the graphic card) unsafe and may have already damaged my PC components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heat can always damage other components, so it really matters how far the card is from other cards and parts.  If there's sufficient case cooling, it should be fine.

My concern would be to ask why your card temperature is reading temps at just below the boiling point of water.  Do you get graphics artifacts at that temperature?  When it reads at that temperature, can you open the case and feel that much heat in the air near it coming off of the card? Either your overclock is dangerous for the card, or there's a busted component somewhere that is causing you to see these kind of numbers.  That could mean the card is on its way out, but it could also mean that you have a bad thermostat on the board that is reading silly temperatures.  The latter is not uncommon with computer components; you may not actually be hitting 96c.

I would cold shutdown the machine for half an hour and immediately measure temps after booting; if it still says 96c while the PC is idle and has had time to cool down, it's probably just a bad sensor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not getting any graphics artifacts when hitting 96 celsius. When idle, it has temperature around 49 celsius and rapidly goes up to 96 for full load. Fans run at 100% speed then. If my board is only reporting a false number, can the number also trigger higher fan rpms and crash my system? The graphics card is a refurbished one that I got from Amazon and I am suspecting that it might not have been fixed.

Comment: While I can rma the graphics card, what I am worried is the chance of my motherboard and other components  having been damaged due to the prolonged period of using graphics card at around 96 celsius. If such chance is slim at the temperature, I will be much relieved.

Comment: I'd RMA the card.  The rest of your gear should be fine.